# Check if people are using my site's content inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

So I am planning on charging people for using my site's content. The way they could use it, is I would give them an iframe, which they could embed into their site.

Now what if someone embeds this iframe into their own site without my permission? 
a) How could I find out which sites are using an iframe of my site?
b) Is there a way to programmatically prohibit such behavior, for example show an error page or just an empty site, if the iframe is embedded into a page, which was not previously verified by me?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Wow, that was quick, thank you a lot, Charlotte! :) And please excuse me for asking such a similar question.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, Chris, as well! :) I will look at both previously asked questions in detail now and mark this one as a duplicate.